# Which binary of Stockfish 7 should I use?

Tags: engines, stockfish

Stockfish 7 for Windows comes with 3 64-bit binaries:

- `stockfish 7 x64 bmi2.exe`
- `stockfish 7 x64 popcnt.exe`
- `stockfish 7 x64.exe`

All 3 of them work on my system. Which one gives the best performance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a terminal/console. Run the stockfish program, if the engine crashes move to the next one.

Type `bench` for the working binaries, and pick the one with best nodes/second.

[image]

Comment: OK, and go with the one with lowest total time?

Comment: @M.M The more nodes per second, the better.

Comment: Empirical analysis is the best : )

Answer (score 4):

I think in general, the 'best' is x64_bmi2, then x64_popcnt, then x64 and x32 is 'worst'. That said, if your processor doesn't support bmi2 it won't run, etc. So pick the best one that doesn't crash.

To confirm this I ran the benchmarks given above.

On my PC (nodes/sec):
stockfish_32: 1380872
stockfish_64: 1764951
stockfish_64_popcnt: 1813557
stockfish_64_bmi2: 1886284